# Flutter: How to reproduce this bottom container who reacts to finger movement

Tags: user-interface, flutter

[image: nordvpn UI]

I would like to reproduce what you see on the bottom. I don't know if it's a kind of popup, but it's react like a GestureDetector: movement to the top enlarge the element and a movement down brings it back. And if it's only a Widget IOS, is there an equivalent for Android ?

Comment: It's a Modal BottomSheet: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html

Comment: Nice, thank you 

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If i understand your question correctly you need bottom sheet that present in dart.
You can find document in [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/BottomSheet-class.html).